# Python Selenium don't click on link unable to locate

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

this is the website:
http://money.finance.sina.com.cn/bond/quotes/sh175694.html

And I tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="title tit06"]/a').click()
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//a[@class="more more_links"])[1]').click()
```

Neither is working and returns: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Here's more :

```
url = 'http://biz.finance.sina.com.cn/suggest/lookup_n.php?country=&q=%09175708'
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//div[@class="list"])[2]/label/a').click()   
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="title tit06"]/a').click()
```

Comment: Are you sure that the xpath is exactly correct? Try executing something that you know works with that xpath to see if you get the same error; if so, you will know there is an issue with the xpath (perhaps a simple typo?).

Also, please show us more of your code.

Comment: In my case, all works fine. I used Firefox

Comment: @Cathy Which link? Update the quesion with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: Please find my updated whole codes here, the error says`
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class="title tit06"]/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.104)`

Comment: @DebanjanB there's already a link in it, thanks

Comment: Umm,  I think there's window handle's thing as I jumped more than one links

Comment: thank you all for helping look into it, fixed when jumped window -1, thanks!